# Pandas groupby data frame for duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
data = dict(t=[0, 1, 0, 1], s=[0, 31, 4, 26])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

How can I use `df.groupby(['t'])` in order to end up with a data frame that looks like this:

```
t    s_0    s_1
0    0      31
1    4      26
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create for each group new row with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and then reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with first level, last some data cleaning:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('t')['s']
         .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.to_numpy()))
         .unstack(0)
         .add_prefix('s_')
         .rename_axis(index='t', columns=None)
         .reset_index()
)
print (df1)
   t  s_0  s_1
0  0    0   31
1  1    4   26
```